# How to use Google App Authentication for a custom PHP Web App?

Tags: php, oauth, google-apps

I have a web app that users upload files to. I want to authenticate users using this app and they all have Google App email. If I can integrate just Google App authentication to my web app, that had be awesome.

I just don't want to convert the app to Google App Engine (Python/Java) or knit a Google App webpage on top of PHP web app to authenticate.

Is there a possibility like - I ask Google, pl authenticate user - if yes? then load page or else - sorry!

Hope I made sense. Any help is much appreciated!

p.s : The web app in question as well as google app email are on the same domain, mycompany.com. (webmail.mycompany.com and myapp.mycompany.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use open auth to do logins with google. The user will need to be redirected to google to login if they aren't logged in yet. Don't know if is what you mean when you say "knit a google app webpage on top of a php webpage" but that is unavoidable.

Take a look here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: I want to let only my domain (Google App Email) users login and not all Google users. Is that possible? (By Knitting a Google App Webpage, I was referring to creation of a django page for authentication). I am ok with Google's signon. Thanks for the link, reading through the details...

Comment: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html - this has support for Google app auth! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google's](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

Comment: Doesn't look like it is a free solution. We have an Enterprise Google App account already.

Comment: @ThinkCode, the link I gave to Google's Open ID Docs is free.  (http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html)  The Google Apps specific docs are here: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html